# camera photo uploaded as a File filetype with phongeap file transfer API

Tags: javascript, php, android

I'm uploading a photo taken by camera to server using file transfer API, however it's uploaded as a File filetype and the name of the photo is without the jpeg extension. The file can still be read as a image when I download, but I need to transfer the photo from the server to other API using the photo url, and the API expects to see the photo in the image filetype.

The javascript code to upload the photo:

```
var imgFilename = "";

//upload photo
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {


  //upload image
  var fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

  //var uri = encodeURI('http://server...');
  var options = new FileUploadOptions(); 
  options.fileKey = "file";
  if(fileName.indexOf('?')==-1){  
    options.fileName = fileName;  
  }else{  
      options.fileName = fileName.substr(0,fileName.indexOf('?'));  
  }
  options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";//文件格式，默认为image/jpeg
  var params = new Object();
  params.value1 = "test";
  params.value2 = "param";
  options.params = params;
  options.chunkedMode = false;
  options.headers = {Connection: "close"};

  var ft = new FileTransfer();

  ft.upload(imageURI, serverURL() + "/upload.php", win, fail, options);
}

function win(r){
    if (imgFilename !=  ""){
        deleteOldImg(imgFilename);
    }
    var arr = JSON.parse(r.response);
    imgFilename = arr[0].result;
    alert(r.response);
}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
try{
$filename = tempnam('images', '');
$new_image_name = basename(preg_replace('"\.tmp$"', '.jpg', $filename));
unlink($filename);

//print_r($_FILES);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "image/user-photo/2/" . $new_image_name);   
$json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=>$new_image_name)) . "]";
echo $json_out;
}
catch(Exception $e) {
$json_out =  "[".json_encode(array("result"=>0))."]";
echo $json_out;
}
?>
```

The error code happens when PHP code is `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'image/user-photo/2/');`
[image]

Comment: When you talk about *File* and *image* filetype, do you mean the mime type? Because that is stored within the file itself, you can't change it without modifying the file.

Comment: mime types are not stored in files. typically they are set by the name of the file, the extension specifically...

Comment: @Uby but the photo is taken by camera and how should it not be image format? I have also set the mime type be jpeg as indicated in the code, I wonder why the filetype is file.

Comment: @dandavis I have elaborated in the comment.

Comment: Mime type info for photos are stored in files, within EXIF headers. What kind of API are you using?

Comment: @Uby the online API is skybiometry which fetch the photo and do facial recognition. I look through my code and didn't find much difference from others.

Comment: And what error are you getting?

Comment: @Uby use with the php code I uploaded above there's no error, just the filetype is wrong. If I change php code to one simple line `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'image/user-photo/2/');`, I will get a long line of error, I will post the error code in a minute.

Comment: @Uby error code uploaded!

Comment: @vivixu to move a file you can't just specify the destination folder, you have to use the full path of your destination file. That's why you're getting that error

Comment: @Uby full path does it mean I need to add server url? And from the error code, file name php1nlKGt shows it's filetype is wrong right?

Comment: @Uby Hi i just found out that pic is in text type